# How do I modify rails associations from the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-relations

I added a relationship a little while ago to users (user has many cars).
But my boss has told me I need to make a new model for companies which the 
cars will belong to the company and the leases will reside with the company so 
company leases to many uses.
I can't find the specific migration that added the user_id to cars,
so is there a way to say modify?

```
rails g migration user_id_to_company_id_on_cars
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the question is hard to understand. Why should you modify rails association from command line, I think it is just `belongs_to or has_many` in the model?

If you want to do a migration on a model, you can do for example:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_cars user_id:integer
```

Comment: I already have cars to users with a foreign key. What I need to do is change the foreign key to company_id.